# Fortran - explicit interface

Tags: compilation, fortran, explicit-interface

I'm very new to Fortran, and for my research I need to get a monster of a model running, so I am learning as I am going along. So I'm sorry if I ask a "stupid" question. 
I'm trying to compile (Mac OSX, from the command line) and I've already managed to solve a few things, but now I've come across something I am not sure how to fix. I think I get the idea behind the error, but again, not sure how to fix.

The model is huge, so I will only post the code sections that I think are relevant (though I could be wrong). I have a file with several subroutines, that starts with:

```
    !==========================================================================================!
!    This subroutine simply updates the budget variables.                                  !
!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
subroutine update_budget(csite,lsl,ipaa,ipaz)

   use ed_state_vars, only : sitetype     ! ! structure
   implicit none

   !----- Arguments -----------------------------------------------------------------------!
   type(sitetype)  , target     :: csite
   integer         , intent(in) :: lsl
   integer         , intent(in) :: ipaa
   integer         , intent(in) :: ipaz
   !----- Local variables. ----------------------------------------------------------------!
   integer                      :: ipa
   !----- External functions. -------------------------------------------------------------!
   real            , external   :: compute_water_storage
   real            , external   :: compute_energy_storage
   real            , external   :: compute_co2_storage
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!


   do ipa=ipaa,ipaz
      !------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
      !      Computing the storage terms for CO2, energy, and water budgets.               !
      !------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
      csite%co2budget_initialstorage(ipa) = compute_co2_storage(csite,ipa)
      csite%wbudget_initialstorage(ipa)   = compute_water_storage(csite,lsl,ipa)
      csite%ebudget_initialstorage(ipa)   = compute_energy_storage(csite,lsl,ipa)
   end do

   return
end subroutine update_budget
!==========================================================================================!
!==========================================================================================!
```

I get error messages along the lines of

budget_utils.f90:20.54:

real            , external   :: compute_co2_storage
                                                      1
Error: Dummy argument 'csite' of procedure 'compute_co2_storage' at (1) has an attribute that requires an explicit interface for this procedure

(I get a bunch of them, but they are essentially all the same). Now, looking at ed_state_vars.f90 (which is "used" in the subroutine), I find

```
!============================================================================!
!============================================================================!
  !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!  
  ! Site type:
  ! The following are the patch level arrays that populate the current site.
  !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!  

type sitetype


     integer :: npatches

     !  The global index of the first cohort in all patches
     integer,pointer,dimension(:) :: paco_id

     ! The number of cohorts in each patch
     integer,pointer,dimension(:) :: paco_n

     ! Global index of the first patch in this vector, across all patches
     ! on the grid

     integer :: paglob_id

     ! The patches containing the cohort arrays
     type(patchtype),pointer,dimension(:) :: patch
```

Etc etc - this goes one for another 500 lines or so.
So to get to the point, it seems like the original subroutine needs an explicit interface for its procedures in order to be able to use the (dummy) argument csite. Again, I am SO NEW to Fortran, but I am really trying to understand how it "thinks". I have been searching what it means to have an explicit interface, when (and how!) to use it etc. But I can't figure out how it applies in my case. Should I maybe use a different compiler (Intel?). Any hints?

Edit: So `csite` is declared a `target` in all procedures and from the declaration `type(site type)` contains a whole bunch of `pointer`s, as specified in `sitetype`. But `sitetype` is being properly `use`d from another module (`ed_state_vars.f90`) in all procedures. So I am still confused why it gives me the explicit interface error?

Comment: Are `compute_water_storage` and the other functions in your module?

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `csite` in `compute_co2_storage()` because the error message is referring to the declared attributes in that routine rather than those in `update_budget()`.  I suspect it's declared `OPTIONAL` or `POINTER` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. @SethMMorton: yes, as `real function`. @Deditos: in `compute_co2_storage()`, `csite` is declared the same as in the subroutine I posted: `type(sitetype)  , target     :: csite`.

Comment: @Geraldine ever sort this out? having the same issue

Comment: @badgley I think in the end maybe I had issues with my compiler or maybe MPI, or some of the settings in the makefile. I ended up working together with people from our High Performance Computer center at my university, they got it running without problems...

Answer (score 23):

"explicit interface" means that the interface to the procedure (subroutine or function) is declared to the compiler.  This allows the compiler to check consistency of arguments between calls to the procedure and the actual procedure. This can find a lot of programmer mistakes. You can do this writing out the interface with an `interface` statement but there is a far easier method: place the procedure into a module and `use` that module from any other entity that calls it -- from the main program or any procedure that is itself not in the module.  But you don't `use` a procedure from another procedure in the same module -- they are automatically known to each other.

Placing a procedure into a module automatically makes its interface known to the compiler and available for cross-checking when it is `use`ed. This is easier and less prone to mistakes than writing an interface. With an interface, you have to duplicate the procedure argument list.  Then if you revise the procedure, you also have to revise the calls (of course!) but also the interface.

An explicit interface (`interface` statement or module) is required when you use "advanced" arguments.  Otherwise the compiler doesn't know to generate the correct call

If you have a procedure that is `use`ed, you shouldn't describe it with `external`.   There are very few uses of `external` in modern Fortran -- so, remove the `external` attributes, put all of your procedures into a module, and `use` them.

Comment: It may be pretty hard to convert a million line model to modules though.

Comment: I understand what you're saying (good explanation, thanks!). And the procedures that are being called are `real function`s within the file, so I guess they don't even have to be declared as `external`? Or, since they're not all specifically bundled as a module, they still should? (because yes, as @Vladimir says, this is too large a model to convert everything to modules...). The `real function`s use information from another file (see my edit of the original question), but they use `use` (to get `sitetype`, which is used to declare `csite`).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problems you encountered whilst I was trying to install ED2 on my mac 10.9. I fixed it by including all the subroutines in that file in a module, that is:

```
module mymodule
contains
subroutine update_budget(csite,lsl,ipaa,ipaz)
other subroutines ecc.
end module mymodule
```

The same thing had to be done to some 10 to 15 other files in the package.
I have compiled all the files and produced the corresponding object files but now I am getting errors about undefined symbols. However I suspect these are independent of the modifications so if someone has the patience this might be a way to solve at least the interface problem.