# How can i return a vector of characters in fortran 90?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm trying to return a vector of strings in fortran 90 but it's not working.

This is my main program and i want to fill in solutions with readFromCSV function.

```
program write_csv   
character(LEN=30) :: fileName;
character(LEN=200) :: head1,head2,head3,head4,head5
character(len=50), dimension(10), external :: readFromCSV
character(len=50), dimension(10) :: solutions

fileName = "solutions.csv";
solutions = readFromCSV(fileName)
end program
```

ReadFromCSC function code:

```
function readFromCSV(fileName) result (solutions)
integer :: res
character(len=50), dimension(10) :: solutions
character(LEN=10) :: aux, aux2
character(LEN=30) :: fileName
open(10, file=fileName,access='sequential',form="formatted",iostat=res)

i = 1;
DO WHILE (i < 11)
    read(10,fmt='(A)', iostat=res) solutions(i)
    if(i < 10) THEN
        solutions(i) = TRIM(solutions(i))
        solutions(i) = solutions(i)(19:(LEN(solutions(i))))
    ELSE
        solutions(i) = TRIM(solutions(i))
        solutions(i) = solutions(i)(20:(LEN(solutions(i))))
    END IF

        aux = solutions(i)(1:7)
        aux2 = solutions(i)(9:LEN(solutions(i)))
        solutions(i) = TRIM(aux)//TRIM(aux2)

    i = i+1
end do
i = 1;
DO WHILE (i < 11)
    write(*,'(a)') (solutions(i))
    i = i+1
end do
readFromCSV = solutions
end function readFromCSV
```

Comment: Please show what makes you think (probably correctly) that it isn't working.  Compiler errors, wrong results?

Comment: Crucially, though, search here for "explicit interface".  As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630662/3157076) you need such a thing in this case.  Many answers will tell you how to make that happen.

Comment: @francescalus the first error that it shows when i compile is that the external atribute generates a conflict with dimension atribute. But if i remove it, it says that readfromcsv is not a variable and the index of the matrix in (1) must be type INTEGER, and it found CHARACTER.

Comment: You can't declare the function result in that way, but must use an interface block or modules (better) or an internal program.  I can't find a good post for you immediately, however.  Those are search terms for you, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492376/1004168

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to use a library that will read the csv file for you, have a look at https://github.com/jacobwilliams/fortran-csv-module

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. And these suggestions are to difficult for such a simple problem. Just turn it into a subroutine instead of a function. `subroutine readFromCSV(fileName,solutions)`