# Trouble with declaring a Fortran Function that returns a list

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
INTEGER FUNCTION NUMTOLIST(NUM) RESULT(LI)
IMPLICIT NONE
! FUNCTION TO CONVERT NUMBERS INTO ARRAYS OF NUMBERS, BY DIGIT

! PROBLEM 1: X IS NOT BEING PASSED

INTEGER :: NUM
INTEGER :: I,J
INTEGER :: LI(0:5) ! G95 COMPILER SAYS THAT 'LI ALREADY HAS BASIC TYPE INTEGER', DOESN'T RECOGNISE AS ARRAY
PRINT *,'NUM: ',NUM ! DEBUGGING LINE, CONFIRMS THAT X IS NOT BEING PASSED INTO THE FUNCTION
DO I = 0,5
  J = 0
  DO WHILE (J*10**(5-I)<=NUM)
    J = J+1
  END DO
  J = J-1
  LI(I) = J
  NUM = NUM-(J*10**(5-I))
END DO

PRINT *,'LI: ',LI ! DEBUGGING LINE, SHOWS THAT FUNCTION IS AS IS SUPPOSED TO, EXCEPT FOR ON SOME SORT OF DEFAULT INTEGER

RETURN

END FUNCTION NUMTOLIST

PROGRAM NUMTOLISTTEST
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER FUNCTION, NUMTOLIST
INTEGER :: X
INTEGER :: F(1:6)
READ *,X
PRINT *,X
F = NUMTOLIST(X)
! PROBLEM 2: THE RESULT OF NUMTOLIST SHOULD BE A LIST, BUT F IS JUST BEING ASSIGNED NUM, NOT THE OUTPUT OF NUMTOLIST
PRINT *,F
READ *,X


END PROGRAM NUMTOLISTTEST
```

Here is my full code. As the name suggests, this is a test for a function of a larger code. There are several problems but the one that is most pressing is that for some reason a variable is not being passed to a function. I am using the silverfrost compiler, and for some reason although everything in the function itself is working as it should, it neither inputs nor returns properly. The input itself is completely disregarded, leading to num being undefined, and the return isn't being read as a list type, as F, when printed, is a list of the arbitrary number num took on. It's completely beyond me why any of this is happening, and I've been on and off looking at this for a couple of days.

Much more trivially, when I try to compile using G95, it won't. It claims that 'Li already has basic type 'Integer'', and then won't recognise Li as a list. The method I'm using to declare an integer as a list has worked in the past for me, and fits the documentation I've seen, so I'm confused why it's throwing an error.

I've been stuck on this for a while, and I just can't seem to fix it on my own. Whatever help is offered will be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: You will need an explicit Interface in this case, because the return type is an array.

Comment: Thank's for your time, do you mind if I ask what exactly an explicit interface is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492376/2938526

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed declaring a type for the variable `LI` twice in the function. Look:

```
INTEGER FUNCTION NUMTOLIST(NUM) RESULT(LI)
! (...)
INTEGER :: LI(0:5)
```

Notice the `INTEGER` keyword before function declaration. It applies to the variable name declared as result in `result(LI)`. The second declaration of `LI` gives the error.

Solutions:

1. Remove the `INTEGER` from the function declaration (preferred);
2. Remove the second type declaration of `LI`. You can specify a dimension without type declaration, with the `dimension` specification statement.

like this:

```
DIMENSION LI(0:5)
```

Besides that, to call a function with an array as a returning value, you will need an explicit interface.