# Why is interface required here for correct results

Tags: floating-point, fortran, ieee-754

Consider the code:

```
subroutine func(i) bind(c)
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: c_float
  implicit none
  real(c_float), value :: i
  print *, i, "+", i, "=", i + i
end subroutine

program main
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: c_float
  implicit none
  real(c_float) :: i = 1.0
  call func(i)
end program
```

It displays `5.61379690E-30 + 5.61379690E-30 = 1.12275938E-29`, which is of course wrong. Only if I add an explicit interface, it outputs the correct results:

```
subroutine func(i) bind(c)
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: c_float
  implicit none
  real(c_float), value :: i
  print *, i, "+", i, "=", i + i
end subroutine

program main
  implicit none
  interface
    subroutine func(i)
      real, value :: i
    end subroutine func
  end interface
  real :: i = 1.0
  call func(i)
end program
```

I then get `1.00000000 + 1.00000000 = 2.00000000` which is correct.

But what is causing the error here? Why is an extra interface required that doesn't add any new information?

I use gfortran, GCC, Version 7.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function or subroutine that has `value` dummy argument requires an explicit interface. The same holds for procedures that have the `bind()` attribute. Otherwise the calling code does not know how to call it properly.

The Fortran 2018 draft states:

> 15.4.2.2  **Explicit interface**
> 1 Within the scope of a procedure identifier, the procedure shall have an explicit interface if it is
> not a statement function and
> ...
> (3)  the procedure has a
> dummy argument that (a)  has the ALLOCATABLE, ASYNCHRONOUS, OPTIONAL,
> POINTER, TARGET, **VALUE**, or VOLATILE attribute, ...
> ...
> (6)  the procedure has the **BIND** attribute.

Note that an [explicit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486822/fortran-explicit-interface) is not the same as the `interface` block you used. The interface block is one of the possible ways how to provide the explicit interface. A better alternative is often to use a module and sometimes to use an internal procedure.

The standard defines explicit interface as:

> 3.90.2
> **explicit interface**
> interface of a procedure that includes all the characteristics of the procedure and names for its dummy arguments
> except for asterisk dummy arguments (15.4.2)

That is different form an `interface` block, that is an actual piece of code that starts with the `interface` keyword.

Comment: Ok this is good to know, thank you. But why is the interface not an explicit? I got the syntax from [this](https://w3.pppl.gov/~hammett/comp/f90tut/f90.tut4.html) tutorial (section interface blocks) which refered to it as 'explicit' (but didn't mention it is required for value arguments, only optional, keyword, pointer, etc.)... How can I change the interface in the question so that it is really explicit and correct?

Comment: @user3137490 Your interface block in the second sample DOES provide an explicit interface. In your first code sample the function is external so the interface is implicit.

Comment: @user3137490 Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486822/fortran-explicit-interface

Comment: Just stick all your subroutines and functions in modules, then you will never have to worry about this, and gain other advantages as well.