# Passing a subroutine as an arugment to another subroutine

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I am trying to pass a Fortran `subroutine` as an argument to another `subroutine`. I want to do this so I can write a general `module` (e.g. for root finding) where I can then define various `subroutines` to be called by my general `subroutine`, which should be reusable. This is the second Fortran code I have written and my background is in Python, so my idea of how to write code is based on how I would write Python code (this probably results in Fortran code written with bad practice, but I am trying to learn).

I have figured out how to do what I want using functions, but I want to do the same thing with `subroutines`.

My issue is I am unsure how to declare (not sure if that's the right word) the `subroutine` argument in the generic `subroutine`. If it were a `function`, it would just be, for example, `real :: f`, but I am unsure what the equivalent is (if one exists) for `subroutines`.

`main.f90`:

```
program main
    use mod1, only : sub1
    use mod2, only : sub2
    implicit none

    real :: a, b

    a = 0.2

    call sub2(sub1, a, b)

    print *, b, exp(sqrt(a))
end program main
```

`mod1.f90` (this contains the `subroutine` that I want to be called from another `subroutine`):

```
module mod1
    implicit none

    public sub1
    
contains
    subroutine sub1(arg1,  arg2)
        real, intent(in) :: arg1
        real, intent(out) ::  arg2

        arg2 = sqrt(arg1)
    end subroutine sub1
end module mod1
```

`mod2.f90` (this contains the generic `subroutine` that I want to be able to pass other `subroutines` to):

```
module mod2
    implicit none

    public sub2
    
contains
    subroutine sub2(other_sub, arg1,  arg2)
        ???? :: other_sub   ! this is the line I am unsure of
        real, intent(in) :: arg1
        real, intent(inout) :: arg2

        call other_sub(arg1, arg2)
        arg2 = exp(arg2)
    end subroutine sub2
end module mod2
```

Once I have the syntax right, I plan to compile as:

```
gfortran mod1.f90 mod2.f90 main.f90
```

I can share the equivalent Python code or Fortran with passing a function if people think it is relevant/helpful/clarifying.

Comment: Is there a reason you intend to write `real :: f` for a function instead of declaring the explicit interface of `f` as an argument? If you specify the interface of a function argument, the way to have a subroutine follows naturally.

Comment: `procedure() :: s`, that is, could work, but it's just as "wrong" as `real :: f`.

Comment: @francescalus The reason I didn’t do it with that way is simply because I don’t know about interfaces and how to do that in the generic way I’m looking to use (i.e. I thought interfaces constrain what the subroutine can look like, such as how many arguments it takes).

Comment: There are times when one "needs" to use an implicit interface (like `external :: f, sub`, or `real :: f`) but if those aren't your cases, then the approaches in the linked question and answers should suit.

Comment: If you're happy with the explicit interfaces as linked, we can leave it at that. But if you need the implicit interface we can address that complication after an [edit]. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, we can find further explanation.

Comment: I see how to do it with the explicit interfaces in the marked duplicate, but I would also be interested in seeing what you mean by an implicit interface since I don't know what that is. What would you like me to change about my question to make it more suitable for that?

Comment: If you don't need an implicit interface, and don't already know what an implicit interface is, then I think we'd cause you harm by trying to explain.  As is good advice for Fortran generally: always use explicit interfaces. If you can't use an explicit interface, redesign things so you can. If you still need an implicit interface, grab a beer and wonder how nice life could be with a beer and no implicit interfaces in sight.

Comment: Understood. Just to clarify, using `interface` is when you have an explicit interface, correct?

Comment: Yes, using `interface` or `procedure(example_sub)` (in the example of the accepted answer over there) are the explicit interface ways. `external example_sub` and `procedure() example_sub` are the implicit interface ways you need to pretend don't exist.

Comment: @jared See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486822/fortran-explicit-interface for more about explicit interface. It is not just about procedure arguments. Normal subroutines and functions have an explicit interface because they are in a module.  no `interface` keyword is used.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Got it. But to be clear, there's no clean way to do that in my case right? From what I understand, it would require `use` which can only be done if you know a priori the name of the module to reference. Is that correct? (We should probably avoid a long discussion in the comments, so let me know if you want to start a chat or if there's already a fortran chat to use.)

Comment: @jared I just wanted to clarify what "explicit interface" means. See the previous comment by francescalus and the answers in the linked Q/A for the ways possible here. `interface` blocks or `procedure` statements are available.