# Dealing with interface argument type mismatch

Tags: fortran

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77875986/12131013) about passing a subroutine as an argument to another subroutine, the consensus was that I should use an explicit `interface`. The issue I am running into is writing the interface in such a way that allows the user to use whichever precision they'd like for their. Below I have an example to illustrate this issue. Notice how `sub1` defines the arguments to be `real(8)` while `sub2` thinks that everything is `real(4)` (the default). This results in the compilation error reproduced at the end.

So, is there a way to enable the user to choose their own precision for the calculations? Bear in mind I am using Fortran 95.

`main.f90`

```
program main
    use mod1, only : sub1
    use mod2, only : sub2
    implicit none

    real :: a, b

    a = 0.2
    
    call sub2(sub1, a, b)

    print *, b, exp(sqrt(a))
end program main
```

`mod1.f90`

```
module mod1
    implicit none

    public sub1
    
contains
    subroutine sub1(arg1,  arg2)
        real(8), intent(in) :: arg1
        real(8), intent(out) ::  arg2

        arg2 = sqrt(arg1)
    end subroutine sub1
end module mod1
```

`mod2.f90`

```
module mod2
    implicit none

    public sub2    
contains
    subroutine sub2(other_sub, arg1,  arg2)
        interface
            subroutine other_sub(arg1,  arg2)
                real, intent(in) :: arg1
                real, intent(out) :: arg2
            end subroutine other_sub
        end interface
        real, intent(in) :: arg1
        real, intent(inout) :: arg2

        call other_sub(arg1, arg2)
        arg2 = exp(arg2)
    end subroutine sub2
end module mod2
```

Compilation:

```
$ gfortran -c mod1.f90 mod2.f90 -std=f95
$ gfortran mod1.o mod2.o main.f90 -std=f95
```

Error:

```
main.f90:10:14:

   10 |     call sub2(sub1, a, b)
      |              1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘other_sub’ at (1): Type mismatch in argument 'arg1' (REAL(4)/REAL(8))
```

Comment: Fortran doesn't have template procedures (yet).

Comment: @lastchance So, in general, the user needs to make sure they use the same precision as what is used in the subroutine?

Comment: Well, you can have overloaded routines for different types with a common generic name but you do still have to write the routines for all those different types. Yes, Fortran is very type-sensitive and you have to match types in the procedure call. I often use real(kind=RKIND) throughout, with RKIND a single parameter set in a module. Then at least all my real variable types match.

Comment: I have a `kind_parameter` module following https://fortran-lang.org/learn/best_practices/floating_point/ which I use for the datatypes. Would I then have include `use kind_parameter, only : dp` in `sub1`, `sub2`, and `other_sub` (the interface)?

Comment: No, but you have to make sure that the kind matches. Using the module could be the simplest way.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Is that a response to my last comment? If so, "no" means I don't have to use a module or are you saying if I have a module I don't have to use `use`?

Comment: You do have to use `use` if you want to use the module.